# CSS position absolute and position relative bug in IE

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a simple html and CSS thingy :
I have a huge div with position relative, and then lots of a links that containing a position absolute ..

it works fine in FF and chrome, but very badly in IE.

it seems that in IE the positioning is bad, and also not getting the "margin: 0 auto;" thingy..

this is my code :

HTML:

```
<div class="wpr">
<a href="http://www.leumi.co.il/" target="_blank" id="leumi"></a>
<a href="http://www.oren-ins.co.il/" target="_blank" id="oren"></a>
<a href="http://www.energy.org.il/" target="_blank" id="energy"></a>
<a href="http://www.lionorl.co.il/" target="_blank" id="leon"></a>
<a href="http://www.calcalist.co.il/" target="_blank" id="yit"></a>
<a href="http://www.yit.co.il/" target="_blank" id="calcalist"></a>
<a href="https://events.eventact.com/runreg/event/regform.aspx?event=4243&company=204&form=1617&account=0&lang=he&login=562974333928" target="_blank" id="register"><img src="sign.gif" alt="register" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
.wpr
    {

        background: url('bg_page.gif') no-repeat 0 0 ;
        width: 980px; height: 643px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;
        }

        #leumi{ position: absolute;  top: 181px; right:96px ; width: 102px; height: 30px; }
        #oren{ position: absolute;  top: 176px; right:227px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
        #energy{ position: absolute;  top: 176px; right:380px ; width: 139px; height: 43px;}
        #leon{ position: absolute;  top: 510px; right:812px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
        #calcalist{ position: absolute;  top: 584px; right:841px ; width: 139px; height: 43px;}
        #yit{ position: absolute;  top: 579px; right:0px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
        #register{ position: absolute;  top: 444px; right:808px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
```

Comment: Have you closed the `div` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it worked out for me if Im having a  tag wrapping it..
thats not the most elegant way to solve it, but it worked.

**Heres the code:**

```
    <table align="center" >
<tr>
<td>
<div class="wpr">
    <a href="http://....il/" target="_blank" id="leumi"></a>
    <a href="http://...co.il/" target="_blank" id="oren"></a>
    <a href="http://....il/" target="_blank" id="energy"></a>
    <a href="http://..." target="_blank" id="leon"></a>
    <a href="http://../" target="_blank" id="yit"></a>
    <a href="http://..." target="_blank" id="calcalist"></a>
    <a href="https://events.eventact.com/runreg/event/regform.aspx?event=4243&company=204&form=1617&account=0&lang=he&login=562974333928" target="_blank" id="register"><img src="sign.gif" alt="register" /></a>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
    table 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
    .wpr
    {

        background: url('bg_page.gif') no-repeat 0 0 ;
        width: 980px; height: 643px; position: relative;overflow:hidden;
    }

        #leumi{ position: absolute;  top: 181px; right:96px ; width: 102px; height: 30px; }
        #oren{ position: absolute;  top: 176px; right:227px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
        #energy{ position: absolute;  top: 176px; right:380px ; width: 139px; height: 43px;}
        #leon{ position: absolute;  top: 510px; right:812px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
        #calcalist{ position: absolute;  top: 584px; right:841px ; width: 139px; height: 43px;}
        #yit{ position: absolute;  top: 579px; right:0px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
        #register{ position: absolute;  top: 444px; right:790px ; width: 139px; height: 43px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine in Chrome & FireFox, because they auto-correct your HTML code. so if you make an error, like not closing a `<div>` they will close it for you.
IE will not close it, and shows you an incorrect layout, not what you expecting.
In that case IE is the only browser how does it correct, but because of all the bashing, everybody would think IE is the browser that handled it incorrect.

And for doctype, use this:

`<!doctype html>`

Your CSS code is missing something, `<a>` is an inline element, so height en width will not work unless you make it a block element.

```
.wpr a {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add `left` and `top` property in your `.wpr` class

Answer (score 0):

Which doc type and IE version are you using?

Try using;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```